# SlideShow Image in XamarinAndroid

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I tried to download the slideshow Android jar file I used in xamarin android, but I did not see what I could download. Please give me a guide to grab a slideshow of **xamarin android**. I did not see anything in Nuggets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to use [InfiniteCycleViewPager for Xamarin.Android](https://github.com/martijn00/InfiniteCycleViewPagerXamarin).

And it also avaliable in [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugins.Android.InfiniteCycleViewPager/) :

```
Install-Package Xam.Plugins.Android.InfiniteCycleViewPager -Version 1.0.2
```